# How can I make a div adopt the height of the screen?

Tags: css, html, height

I tried using

```
height: 100%
```

but this makes the div only as high as its contents - it just contains a single word of text.

How can I force the div to use the screen height instead?

Comment: Please post your HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need the `body` and `html` elements to have `100%` height as well.

Try the following CSS:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

YourDivSelector {
    height: 100%;
}
```

The margin and padding must be set to 0 to prevent autoscroll in Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

You should set all the containers that contain the div to height:100% as well, including the body and html tags.

Comment: This was what I needed but I gave SLaks the answer tag because his came before yours. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You also need to set html and body to height:100%;

```
 html,body{height:100%}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Setting the html and body height to 100% didn't work, but when I combined min-height of 100vh and a height of 100% on the div it worked.

```
html, body {
   height: 100%;
}

div {
   min-height: 100vh; 
   height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the width and height of the window [using JavaScript](http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/browserwindow) and then use those values to set the height and width of the `div`, as needed.

Answer (score 0):

maybe

```
min-height:100%;
```

what are you trying to do exactly? post some more info and we can help you more

Answer (score 0):

You can only meaningfully use height=100% if its containing element's height is definided. Its 100%, of what? no height if defined anywhere. You can use javascript to get the height of the current window (as previously mentioned), or specify a specific height of 800px or whatever value. :D