# How to Set Height of a div same as the Screen Height

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6, height, document

I need a div height changable if the screen size changes.

I also need that div is scrollable because the content may be Large.
But only when it is larger than the screen zize.

Also it should Work on IE6

Is there any Possibility for that?

If yes,
Please Give me the Complete css, html and javascript.

Comment: See this existing [StackOverflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1095563/how-can-i-make-a-div-adopt-the-height-of-the-screen)

Answer (score 3):

set width 100%; It's works

```
body {
width:100%;
height:100%;
}

#wrapper {
width:100%;
background:#ccc;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if the div is a direct child of body than just set height: 100% on both the div and the body. Like this:

```
body, #your-div-id {
   height: 100%;
}
```

As far the scrillability is concerned just go:

```
#your-div-id {
   overflow: auto;
}
```

Makes sense to you?