# Bootstrap 3 panel height 100%

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've been trying this for a while and cannot get it working.   Basically, I need the Bootstrap panel (border) to take up 100% of the window.  But it seems that it is only taken a fix height and not the 100%.  Here is my [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/7fEoqWp8gNTnG8A3QceG?p=preview).

Comment: try to set `height` for your #container instead of `min-height` see also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12172256/1596547

Answer (score 3):

Use this jquery function, add the class full-height to the panel.

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    $('.panel.full-height').each(function() {
        $(this).height($(window).height() - $(this).offset().top - 20);
    });
    $('#results').height($(window).height() - $('#results').offset().top - 106);
});
setTimeout(function() { $(window).resize(); },200);
```