# Dynamic panel Height based on screen size

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How to get the panel height to increase dynamically based on screen size

```
<div class="container-fluid">


<!--Heading-->
<div class="row " align="center">
    <h1 style="font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif; font-size: 45px;"> Test Automation Inventory</h1>
</div>


<!--Table-->
<div class="row" >
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" ng-click="Reset()">&nbsp;Add New Test Details</button>
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading ">
                <h3 class=" panel-title pull-left" style="padding-top:7.5px">Test Automation Inventory</h3>

                <div class="input-group">
                    <input id="Special" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" autocomplete="off" focus ng-model="FilterItems">
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- style="overflow:auto; height:670px"-->
            <div class="panel-body scroll" style="overflow:auto; height:670px">

                <table class="table table-striped table-hover">

                    <tr ng-show="results.length==0">
                        <td style="vertical-align:middle;">No data found</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th ng-repeat="c in columns" ng-click="ChangeOrder(c)">{{c.text}}</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="animate-repeat" ng-repeat="Res in results | filter:FilterItems | orderBy: Column:reverse ">
                        <td> {{$index+1}}</td>
                        <td>{{Res.Test_Inventory_Group}}</td>
                        <td>{{Res.Test_Inventory_Application}}</td>
                        <td>{{Res.Test_Inventory_Count}}</td>
                        <td>
                            <button class="btn btn-danger">Delete Test</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                </table>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have a table inside panel body. where dynamically data would get added to it.
I want the panel to have scroll but it main page should not get the scroll.
The panel height to be [Windowheight - 10px]

[Web page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ak2S.png)

I don't want the page to have scroll, I want only the panel to have scroll

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set div height equal to screen size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12172177/set-div-height-equal-to-screen-size)

Answer (score 1):

Try this css code:

```
.panel-body.scroll {  height: calc(100vh - 200px);  }
```

Or

```
<div class="panel-body scroll" style="overflow:auto; height: calc(100vh - 200px);">
```

More details:

- `100vh` is `100%` viewport height/screen's height. [See more](https://www.sitepoint.com/css-viewport-units-quick-start/).
- `calc` is a calculator. In this case, it takes 100% of the screen's height and minuses `200px` from it [See more](https://css-tricks.com/a-couple-of-use-cases-for-calc/).

Comment: Delibas It worked, can you please explain what is calc(100vh - 200px);

Answer (score 0):

Instead of **height: 100%;** use **height: 100vh**

the **vh** matches the **height** of the **viewport**.