# In CSS, how can I make a div as high as the entire page?

Tags: css

In CSS, how can I make a div as high as the entire page?

I want to make that div occupy the whole space of the webpage and put a background image in it.

Comment: height:100%; position:absolute; will that work for you?

Comment: `#your-thing { position: absolute; left: 0; right: 0; top: 0; bottom: 0; }`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I make a div adopt the height of the screen?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1095563/how-can-i-make-a-div-adopt-the-height-of-the-screen)

Comment: Do you want it to be on the entire PAGE or entire SCREEN? A page can be larger than a screen

Comment: @FANGYishu Did any of the answers work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SAMPLE FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/apTFp/

```
div{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    left:0px;
    right:0px;
    background-color:#eeeeee;
}
```

This should work :)

Comment: Well, that wouldn't really make the div the same height as the **entire page** but to the same height as the viewport —root element. See an edit to your fiddle setting a higher body: http://jsfiddle.net/apTFp/2/

Comment: Am unable to see your fiddle. Although I think what you're saying was not the requirement.

Comment: Updated the link. Well, one thing is the page, another thing is the viewport. Your solution would be fine if the page is lower than the viewport.

Comment: agree with you that this will not work if the content of the page is larger than the viewport, but then there are techniques to scroll that div itself instead of the viewport, correct ?

Comment: I think in that case, with your code, the easiest way to *fix* it, it's just adding a relative position to the `body` element. So your `div` absolute position will be relative to the body, instead of the root element.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution would be using the unit `vh`. 1 vh equals to 1% of the total viewport height. If you wanna learn more about units, you can checkout this [article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units).

To make the div as high as the entire viewport, simply set `height` to 100vh.

```css
div {
    height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: Wow, this is by far the easiest answer! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Do not need a div in the first place

Try

```
<body style="position: relative; margin: 0; background-color: Blue;">
<p>
    Hello
</p>
</body>
```

Of course change background-color to background image

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<div id="foo"></div>

<script>
$("#foo").css("width", screen.width);
$("#foo").css("height", screen.height);
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do

```
#mainContainer { 
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url('imagePath'); //you can add a repeat or no repeat here
}
```

Hope it helps or somewhat you can style the body so that you will not specify the width and the height anymore, just the background image.

Comment: height:100% just won't work alone. You'd have to do other things to enable the height to be 100%