# How to set div height value dynamically?

Tags: html, asp.net, css

I have a HTML page and include 3 div like this:
[**Link**](http://jsfiddle.net/8DR3U/1/)

```
<div style="min-height:100%;">
        <div id="TopContent" style="display: inline-block; height: 100px; width: 100%; background-color: #CCDEBB;">
        </div>

        <div id="LeftContent" style="display: inline-block; width: 25%; border: 3px solid #DFE8F6;">

                </div>             

        <div id="RightContent" style="border: 3px solid #b8cfee; display: inline-block; float: right; width: 72%;">


        </div>

            </div>
```

I want to set height value of LeftContent and RightContent according to page height value. I mean  LeftContent and RightContent height extend end of the page.

Answer (score 1):

Use calc();

```
#LeftContent{
float:left;
margin-right:3px;
height:calc(100% - 100px); //-100px because height of top bar is 100px

}
```

same for Right Content

Answer (score 1):

You can't control height with this HTML, but you can emulate this effect with :before/:after elements:

```
#LeftContent:after,
#RightContent:after{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:9999px;
    z-index:-1;
    background:#DFE8F6;
}
#RightContent:after{background:#b8cfee;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EhnhZ/

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use classes instead of id.

HTML

```
<div class="content top"></div>
<div class="content left"></div>
<div class="content right"></div>
```

CSS

```
*{
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  margin:0;
} /* instead of HTML and BODY attributes */

.content{
  display:inline-block;
  margin-right:-4px; /*to margin left div with the right one!*/
  margin-top:-4px; /*to margin left and right divs with the top one!*/
}

.left{
  height:calc(100% - 200px); /*use calc(100% - "top div height" */
  width:50%; /*choose your own width*/
  background-color:red;
}

.right {
  height: calc(100% - 200px); /*use calc(100% - "top div height" */
  width:50%; /*choose your own width*/
  background-color:green;
}

.top{
  width:100%;
  height:200px;
  background-color:blue;
}
```

Hope this can help you! ( see more on http://codepen.io/utopy/pen/zcyti )

Answer (score 0):

Like this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8DR3U/2/)?

just add `float: left;` to LeftContent

Comment: Your fiddle appears nicer than his but the OP is asking for the height of the `Left` and `Right` divs to be the height of the page.

Answer (score 0):

I built my answer using the answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1095563/how-can-i-make-a-div-adopt-the-height-of-the-screen/1095581#1095581)

```
<style>
    html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
</style>

<div style="min-height:100%;height:100%;">
    <div id="TopContent" style="height: 100px; width: 100%; background-color: #CCDEBB;">
    </div>

    <div id="LeftContent" style="min-height:100%;width: 25%; border: 3px solid #DFE8F6;float:left">    
    </div>             

    <div id="RightContent" style="min-height:100%;border: 3px solid #b8cfee; width:72%;float:right">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: With this HTML you have vertical scroll. It is incorrect. And if you add content on each block height of parrent div (<div style="min-height:100%;height:100%;">) dont't change. If use backgrond for this div it's not stretch. http://jsfiddle.net/YDtgU/ ... This is a terrible answer and incorrect implementation

Comment: @Anon the vertical scroll is as the OP asked ("LeftContent and RightContent height extend end of the page"). I think you should read what the OP wanted before deciding whether this is incorrect... and it has been accepted as an answer therefore = correct.

Comment: Vertical scroll without huge page height is unacceptable. I think that OP wants that block height = page height. Your code is very hard.

Answer (score 0):

At current your solution will not work, this is because of how web page `documents` render.

At the moment from your HTML your current document is the following height :

```
100px (from TopContent)

+ 3px (from LeftContent)

+ 3px (from RightContent)
```

Because the `document` does not need to be larger than `106px` (based on the content) then the `document` element will not render as more than that.

What you can do to trick this is by setting the body/html CSS attributes to have a height of 100%.

Use the following CSS to do this :

```
body,html {
    height:100%;
}
```

Also you will need to set the height of your container div to be as

```
<div style="height:100%;">
```

Here is an example [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2b8TX/1/) for your problem.

Comment: as a result you will always get a vertical scroll that is as high as the `TopContent` which is obviously not needed

Answer (score -2):

You should use jquery,in this event set the height of divs

```
$(window).resize(function () {
 $('#LeftContent').css('height',$(window).height());
 $('#RightContent').css('height',$(window).height());
        });
```

Comment: jQuery or Javascript has not been tagged in this question.

Comment: @Nunners, I'd say it is not a problem :) Users often forget to use proper tags... and if an answer provides a solution (not in this case, but generally) it is OK to do that, imo